# Условные переходы if c#

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста разобраться не пойму, как добавит третьего оператора, задача такая при вводе роста, программа говорит, какого роста человек среднего высокого или маленького

например от 60 до 120 маленький,  от 120 до 179 средний от 180 высокий

Спасибо

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rost;
            Console.WriteLine("KOKOJ U TEBJA ROST");
            rost = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (rost >= 180)
            {
                Console.Write("bolshoj");

            }

            if ( rost <= 179 )
            {
                Console.Write("srednij");
            }
            if (rost < 60 )
            {
                Console.Write("malemkij");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if (rost < 60 )
        {
            Console.Write("malemkij");
        } 
        else if ( rost <= 179 )
        {
            Console.Write("srednij");
        }
        else //if (rost >= 180)
        {
            Console.Write("bolshoj");
        }
```

Comment: вот я тупой )))) спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
        if (rost >= 60 && rost < 120)
        {
            Console.Write("malemkij");
        }
        else if (rost >= 120 && rost < 179)
        {
            Console.Write("srednij");
        }
        else if (rost >= 180)
        {
            Console.Write("bolshoj");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (rost >= 60 && rost < 120)
{
    //
}
else if (rost >= 120 && rost < 179)
{
    //
}
else if (rost >= 180)
{
    //
}
```

Но!!!! Важно еще отметить что в C# 7 есть возможность сделать это же самое через Switch:

```
int rost = 63;

switch (rost)
{
    case int rost when (rost >= 60 && rost < 120):
        //
    break;

    case int rost when (rost >= 120 && rost < 179)
        //
    break;

    case int rost when (rost >= 180);
        //
    break;
}
```

И если уж используется язык версии 7.0 то более правильно использовать вторую конструкцию т.к. банально она более гибкая, хоть и занимает больше места. (добавление условий происходит проще при рефакторинге)

Comment: А не `case bool n when(..)` ? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: для конкретно даного случая -- int. Мы же инт проверяем на рейндж